# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') unit test karma-jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular11

trying to solve this issue it makes all tests failed!
i am using angular 11 with karma-Jasmine,

it happens cuz on one filter method inside function that called in ngOnInt

unit test file

```
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('getMaxDigitalWalletsCount called successfully', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(MockBusinessSettingsService, 'getMaxDigitalWalletsCount').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(MockBusinessSettingsService.getMaxDigitalWalletsCount).toHaveBeenCalled();
    tick(100);
    expect(component.isLoadingResults).toBeFalse();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.ChashInsForm.value).toEqual(
      jasmine.objectContaining({
        maxDigitalWalletsCount: listData.digitalWalletsCountUPG.body.maxDigitalWalletsCount,
      }),
    );
  }));
```

ts file:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getserviceProvider();
}
  getserviceProvider() {
    this.Servicefile.getUpgWalletServiceProviders().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.UpgWalletServiceProviders = data?.body;
        this.ServiceProvider = data?.body;
        this.selectedDisplayName = this.ServiceProvider.filter((t: any) => t.isActive === true)[0].displayName;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorsService.handle(error);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: You need a spy on `MockBusinessSettingsService.filter`.

Comment: can you explain more please ? because   spyOn(MockBusinessSettingsService.filter) make anther error in filter